# I can not get the number of followers on a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the number of followers on a page. That is, obtain the number that appears in the portal as: "1363 people follow this"

I am trying to make the call as follows:

```
Dim urlSocialAnalitics As String = 
   String.Format ("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/friends?summary=total_count&access_token={1}", pIdFanPage, pToken)
```

But it does not work. It's a problem for me.

I have also tried with this url:

```
urlSocialAnalitics = String.Format("graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{0}?fields=fan_count&access_token={1}", pIdFanPage, pToken)
```

But this gives me the number of Likes and not of Followers

I have read the documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/

But I do not see anything about it.

What is the correct call?

Comment: This is not available via API.

Comment: Hi CBroe, Thanks for your comment. Are you sure, that there is no way to know? Thanks.